# Combining two queries into a temporary table, with no similar columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am still relatively new to using Oracle SQL and was looking for some help on this issue I have been trying to work out:

I have two separate queries that I need to somehow join together to create a temporary table with some values. The two queries, that have no overlapping elements are:

```
select
t.segment,
sum(Case when t.cost >= 750000 then 750000 else t.cost end)/sum(t.revenue) as seg_pool

from data3 t
where t.date <= t.forecast_month and t.period = 'Current'
group by t.segment;
```

and

```
select
r.level,
sum(Case when t.cost >= 750000 then 750000 else t.cost end)/sum(revenue) as level_pool,
sum(Case when t.segment = 'S' then t.revenue else 0 end)/sum(t.revenue) as s_weight

from data3 t
left join sb.com r on t.state=r.state and t.cnty=r.cnty
where t.date <= t.forecast_month and t.period = 'Current'
group by r.level;
```

Output from query 1 looks like

```
Segment   Seg_pool
A         .078
B         .09
```

And Output from query 2 looks like

```
Level  Level_pool s_weight
L      .06          .80
M      .08          .82
H      .09          .83
```

What I need to create is a temporary table or singular query that does an arithmetic operation on these values, and outputs it by Segment/Level combination. The arithmetic operation is different for segments A and B:
For L, M, and H, segment A, the formula is

```
A_pool% = levelpool -(segpoolB - segpoolA) ∗ (1 -s_weight)
```

For L, M, and H, segment B, the formula is

```
B_pool% = A_pool% + (segpoolB - segpoolA)
```

So the resulting temp table that I need to produce would look something like this, with "difference" as the difference between the A & B segment pool value

```
Segment Level Pool% s_weight difference
A       L     0.06   0.80     0.12
A       M     0.08   0.82     0.12
A       H     0.09   0.83     0.12
B       L     0.06   0.80     0.12
B       M     0.08   0.82     0.12
B       H     0.09   0.83     0.12
```

Or possibly just getting to this table, which is the final result that I actually need to produce, would be helpful:

```
Segment Level Level_Pool 
A       L     0.0576
A       M     0.07784
A       H     0.08796
B       L     0.0696
B       M     0.08984
B       H     0.0996
```

Any help getting to this final temporary table or query would be much appreciated, or simply a pointing in the right direction on how to combine the two queries I already have set up... thanks, Jordan :)

Comment: I don't see what the relation between A/B and L/M/H is. Is this just a cross join?

Answer (score 0):

`WITH` factoring clause or a CTE (Common Table Expression) might help. For example:

```
WITH a
     AS (  SELECT t.segment,
                    SUM (
                       CASE WHEN t.cost >= 750000 THEN 750000 ELSE t.cost END)
                  / SUM (t.revenue)
                     AS seg_pool
             FROM data3 t
            WHERE     t.date <= t.forecast_month
                  AND t.period = 'Current'
         GROUP BY t.segment),
     b
     AS (  SELECT r.LEVEL,
                    SUM (
                       CASE WHEN t.cost >= 750000 THEN 750000 ELSE t.cost END)
                  / SUM (revenue)
                     AS level_pool,
                    SUM (CASE WHEN t.segment = 'S' THEN t.revenue ELSE 0 END)
                  / SUM (t.revenue)
                     AS s_weight
             FROM data3 t
                  LEFT JOIN sb.com r
                     ON     t.state = r.state
                        AND t.cnty = r.cnty
            WHERE     t.date <= t.forecast_month
                  AND t.period = 'Current'
         GROUP BY r.LEVEL)
SELECT whatever
  FROM a join b on ...
  WHERE ...
```

I didn't quite understand how to get the final result, but - if you know how to join those two queries, now you have a *mechanism* to do it.

Comment: I am still confused on how the select /from/where at the bottom of your response works, seeing as there are no overlapping elements to do the a join b part

Comment: I am having no luck with the Select/From/Join/Where part at the bottom of your response :(

Comment: Just as @eaolson commented under your question, I don't see relation between those two result sets. I was hoping that you do. If you do not, then you'll have to explain how to get from *A* to *B*. If a single query can't do that (or is way too complex), see whether switching to PL/SQL does any good.